# WPF Application and WPF Browser Application

Tags: c#, wpf

I have Prepared a little Phonebook using WPF Application. Now I want to run this application using browser IE and Firefox and Chrome etc.

Update me ! How can I run this on different browser .

Comment: By "WPF application" do you mean a desktop or Windows Client app? Those run on Windows, not a browser. Or do you mean an XBAP page? Only IE can run those.

Answer (score 2):

Form [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970060.aspx)

> ```
> XAML browser applications (XBAPs) combines features of both Web
> ```
>
> applications and rich-client applications. Like Web applications,
>   XBAPs can be deployed to a Web server and started from Internet
>   Explorer or Firefox.

That means if you want to support Chrome, Opera, whatever you should look for [Silverlight](http://www.silverlight.net/)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is you can't. You'll have to port it to a Web Based Technology. The closest thing to this given your Cross Browser requirement is Silverlight.

[There's no automatic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212111/convert-wpf-application-to-silverlight) way of doing this however.

Answer (score 0):

To have a single code base that can run as either a stand-alone Windows application or a web based application Silverlight is probably what you need to use.

Both WPF and Silverlight use XAML to define their UI's and C# as the main application. However, there are differences in the implementations so your WPF code won't work "as is", you'll have to translate it into the Silverlight dialect. If you use the latest Silverlight (4 which is fully released or 5 which is at RC stage) then the differences will be reduced.

You can then compile this to be either a browser based application, out of browser application (basically it instantiates it's own browser to run in) or full trust Windows application. The web version will run on most browsers (IE, Firefox, Chrome, Safari and Opera) under Windows and will also run in Safari on Mac OSX.